# How to stop labels extending beyond the end of the scrollarea?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

In my program, I have a tooltip system so if a string of text cannot fit into a fixed size label, the full message can be displayed in a separate label on hover of the fixed label. These labels are contained within a scrollarea. My issue is that since the label adjusts size horizontally, the second labels full message contents are lost when it exceeds the scroll area. Is there a way to make my program recognise that the label is going to exceed the scroll area and so shift itself to the right in order to have sufficient room to display the full message. Below is a simplified version of the code I am talking about.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


import sys

class Ui_MainWindow():

  def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
     MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
     MainWindow.showMaximized()

     self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
     self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
     self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
     self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 600, 300))
     self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
     self.scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
     self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(False)

     self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
     self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
     self.scrollArea.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
    
     self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
    
     MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

     self.add_label("THANKS FOR ANSWERING MY QUESTION")


  #LABELS ADDED WITH NAME DESCRIPTION
  def add_label(self, name):
      self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 10, 600, 300))

     #Short Message and Tooltip assigned to central and scrollarea
    
     self.short_msg = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
     self.short_msg = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
     self.tooltip = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
     self.tooltip = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
     self.tooltip2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
     self.tooltip2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)

     #IF LABEL EXCEEDS LABEL LENGTH ECLIPSES ADDED AND TOOLTIP LABEL ADDED
     if len(name) > 25:
         #CURRENT ISSUE
         self.short_msg.setText("  " + name[0:22] + "..." + "  ")
         self.tooltip.setText("  " + name + "  ")
         self.tooltip.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 50, 169, 30))
         self.tooltip.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(44, 44, 44, 140); color: black;")
         self.tooltip.setFixedHeight(25)
         self.tooltip.setMinimumWidth(167)
         self.tooltip.adjustSize()
         self.tooltip.hide()

         #IDEAL EXAMPLE Of HOW TOOLTIP SHOULD APPEAR
         self.tooltip2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(363, 80, 169, 30))
         self.tooltip2.setText("  " + name + "  ")
         self.tooltip2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(44, 44, 44, 140); color: black;")
         self.tooltip2.setFixedHeight(25)
         self.tooltip2.setMinimumWidth(167)
         self.tooltip2.adjustSize()
         self.tooltip2.hide()
     else:
         self.short_msg.setText("  " + name + "  ")

     self.short_msg.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 10, 169, 30))
     self.short_msg.setAccessibleName("short_msg")
     self.short_msg.setScaledContents(False)
     self.short_msg.setObjectName("short_msg")      
     self.short_msg.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 120); color: white; text:center;")
   
    
     hover_message(self.short_msg, self.tooltip, self.tooltip2)

class hover_message(QLabel):
  def __init__(self, short_msg, tooltip, tooltip2):
     super(hover_message, self).__init__(short_msg)
     self.stop = False
     self.short_msg = short_msg
     self.short_msg.installEventFilter(self)
     self.short_msg.setMouseTracking(True)

     self.tooltip = tooltip
     self.tooltip2 = tooltip2

 def eventFilter(self, object, event):
    
     if event.type() == QEvent.Enter:
         #THIS IS THE LABEL THAT SHOWS ON HOVER DISPLAYING FULL LABEL NAME
         self.tooltip.show()
         self.tooltip2.show()
         self.stop = True
         return True
     elif event.type() == QEvent.Leave:
         self.tooltip.hide()
         self.tooltip2.hide()
         self.stop = False
     return False



if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
#MainWindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Running this code should show you what I wish to do, I have included an example of what is happening and what I want to happen. The reason I can't apply the ideal example in my own program is because the label will be a different size depending on the message so I can't shift it to the left so it perfectly aligns with the scroll area edge.

Comment: There are a lot of problems with your code, but, most importantly, you are using a fixed geometry (which is actually invalidated by using `adjustSize`, so it's only considered for the positioning); so you either use a layout manager, or compute the position using `QFontMetrics`. In any case, I'd strongly advise you against this whole approach for "tooltips": standard tooltips should be enough, and, forgive my harshness, you don't seem experienced enough (yet) to implement something more advanced that would justify avoiding QToolTip functions.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for the response, I didn't realise PyQt had tooltip functions so I tried to make my own. The inbuilt ones work exactly how I want them to so thanks.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to carefully study the documentation about the base Qt classes, [QObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html) and [QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) (which in turn inherits from QObject), as almost all Qt classes are subclasses of them and thus support their functions. For example, all QWidget subclasses support [`setToolTip()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#toolTip-prop), including, obviously, QLabel (the inheritance is: QLabel > QFrame > QWidget > QObject, so QLabel also has all methods of QFrame, which has all methods of QWidget, etc).